# Range(cells) vba usage

Tags: excel, vba, range

i used to do most of my coding by recording and then finding the parts i need and using them in code. I'm trying to move on to better things and simplifying  simple functions like copying.

But i ran into a problem i don't seem to understand:

```
Sheets("main").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2)).Copy Sheets("Backup").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 2))
```

Ends with an error: Run time error 1004, application defined or object defined error.

While there is no issue while i try to do:

```
Sheets("main").Cells(lastrowMain, lastcolumn).Copy Sheets("Backup").Range("A" + CStr(lastrowBackup + 1))
```

I thought the problem was the size of chosen location to paste to, so i just matched them to be the same, but i still get the same error.

Or maybe my way of choosing a range of cells is wrong and there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem which arises because you have not added a sheet reference to your `Cells`. The active sheet will be assumed in this case and if that is not `main` (or `Backup`) your range will be spanning different sheets, hence the error.

Instead fully qualify along these lines:

```
With Sheets("main")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2)).Copy Sheets("Backup").Range(Sheets("Backup").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Backup").Cells(2, 2))
End With
```

Comment: thank you very much sir! ill make sure to keep working with this logic!